# Why is "Sheila couldn't come to the party, it was a pity." wrong?

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-pronouns

I came across with this exercise in Raymond Murphy's  *English Grammar in Use*:

> Sheila couldn't come to the party, ____ was a pity.

The correct answer is *which*, but I would have said that *it* was equally valid.

It seems to me that *Sheila couldn't come to the party. It was a pity.* and *Sheila couldn't come to the party; it was a pity.* would be correct.

But why is *Sheila couldn't come to the party, it was a pity.* wrong? Does the comma have anything to do?

Comment: When you create two independent sentences, you separate them with a full stop or a semi-colon. A comma is used within one sentence. You can connect two independent sentences with a conjunction, but not with just a comma. "It was a pity" is an independent sentence. Your versions with a full stop and a semi-colon illustrate that. With a comma, it reads like *"I went home, I had a bath" instead of "I went home. I had a bath." or "I went home and I had a bath."

Comment: @oerkelens Would _which_ be used if it were a parentheses instead of a comma?

Comment: @jinawee you could use parenthesis if the comment about it being a pity was an aside, or a comment off the main track of your thoughts. You could use either "which" or "it" in a parenthetical aside. However using "it" sounds somewhat un-fluent to me (AmE native speaker). If you're going to use "it", turn the sentence around and say "It was a pity Sheila couldn't come to the party." However realize this makes your disappointment the main point of the sentence, rather than a secondary commentary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you nailed it correctly. The *comma* is what makes the difference. As oerkelens says, *It was a pity* is an independent sentence and if that is the case, the previous sentence **should** end before it begins.

This tricky question uses *comma* and then asks for the word to put. In simple words, the first part of the sentence gives us the gist and the latter is simply adding the *emotion* or sympathy to it. What we call *supplementary relative clause* is used here and it is often set off by putting comma and then *which*. One good way to identify this is removing the latter part of the sentence *which was pity*. Even after removal, the sentence's meaning is intact and this does not happen in case of *integrated relative clauses*. That said, removing *which* part in such examples will make the sentence looking ungrammatical/weird.

[OxfordDictionaries gives an example of](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/relative-clauses) a restrictive relative clause: `The coat that/which Dan had on yesterday was new.` Remove *which* part and it won't look a proper sentence.

So, to answer you in short, the word is *which* because it introduces *supplementary relative clause* i.e. additional meaning. The comma *before* the word confirms it.